# Dealing with quantization level limiting dsp

Tags: analog, quantization

There is a analog signal in the form as below:

$$ f(t)=A \sin(\omega(t) t+\phi)+B \sin(\omega(t-t_1) t+\phi_1) $$
Where $$B<<A$$

We are going to calculate $\phi, \phi_1, t_1 $,using dsp. But since $B<<A$ and due to quantization level limitation, we can not extract data precisely. Is there any suggetion how to deal with that?

Thank you for your kind replies

Comment: I'd suggest trying non-uniform quantization, increasing the number of quantization levels in the range $(-B,B)$.

Comment: For non-uniform quantization, the quantization noise decreases for low values, but its sabotaged for higher values.

Comment: That's correct, but the higher values have more power, so they can tolerate more noise power too. Just something to consider -- this may not be the solution you need.

Comment: How w(t) is different from w(t-t1)? Do you have a combination of CW wave with chirp?

Comment: f(t) is a combination of a frequency-moduled signal with a time domain shifted version of itself

Comment: Are you sure that such sum may be constructed only in one way?

Comment: For now, the simplest form assumed is this one. Any solution?